# How do I use electron-compile for jade files?

Tags: ecmascript-6, babeljs, electron

This package [electron-compile](https://github.com/electronjs/electron-compile) looks very cool, but I'm having trouble getting it to work. I'm getting this error:

```
Uncaught Exception:
SyntaxError: Unexpected token e
    at Object.parse (native)
    at createCompilerHostFromConfigFileSync (/Users/josh/Projects/jadeElectronTest/node_modules/electron-compile/lib/config-parser.js:406:19)
    at createCompilerHostFromProjectRootSync (/Users/josh/Projects/jadeElectronTest/node_modules/electron-compile/lib/config-parser.js:426:12)
    at Object.init (/Users/josh/Projects/jadeElectronTest/node_modules/electron-compile/lib/config-parser.js:132:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/josh/Projects/jadeElectronTest/app/es6-init.js:7:29)
    at Module._compile (module.js:425:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:432:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:313:12)
    at loadApplicationPackage (/Users/josh/Projects/jadeElectronTest/node_modules/electron-prebuilt/dist/Electron.app/Contents/Resources/default_app/main.js:257:23)
```

I've added  `electron-compile` and `electron-compilers` as a devDependency     according to the instructions.

Here are my files:

**// es6-init.js**

```
var path = require('path');
var appRoot = path.join(__dirname, '..');

require('electron-compile').init(appRoot, './main');
```

**// index.html**

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles/main.less">
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Hello World!</h1>
   We are using Electron
   <script> document.write(process.versions['electron']) </script> on
   <script> document.write(process.platform) </script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
      var fs = require('fs-extra');
      var file = fs.readFileSync('package.json');
      document.write(file);
   </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Any help is appreciated!
Thanks!

**// .compilerc**

```
{
  "env": {
    "development": {
      "application/javascript": {
        "presets": ["es2015"],
        "sourceMaps": "inline"
      },
      "text/less": {
        "dumpLineNumbers": "comments"
      }
    },
    "production": {
      "application/javascript": {
        "presets": ["es2015"],
        "sourceMaps": "none"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What's in your `.configrc` file?

Comment: I'm currently using .compilerc, but I tried .babelrc too. I've updated with the .compilerc file. Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: Your compilerc isn't valid JSON, is that a typo in Stack Overflow?

Comment: Yep. The problem was two fold. That typo, and earlier I had the correct code, but I had the .configrc in the wrong folder. :/
@PaulBetts Thanks for your help!!